# how do I generate a new column in a tibble by combining 2 other columns?

Tags: r

I have a tibble with the variables `Year` and `Quarter` in separate columns in the format '2006' (Year) and '2' (Quarter). I want to merge these to create a new column called `Year_Qtr` in for format 2006-2 or something similar.

I have tried the `unite` function with the code:

```
SA_Long_Data %>%
unite(Year_Qtr, Year, Quarter)
```

This has created the variable I need but produced it as a table rather than a new column within the tibble.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `SA_Long_Data %>% mutate(Year_Qtr = paste0(Year, '_', Quarter))`

Comment: Apologies Renu I had not saw your reply, also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `remove` parameter in `unite` which is `TRUE` by default, set it to `FALSE`. You can also use the `sep` argument to have dashes instead of underscores.

```
library(tidyverse)
SA_Long_Data <- tibble::tibble(Year=1:3,Quarter=5:7)
SA_Long_Data %>% unite(Year_Qtr, Year, Quarter,remove = FALSE,sep="-")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Year_Qtr  Year Quarter
*    <chr> <int>   <int>
1      1-5     1       5
2      2-6     2       6
3      3-7     3       7
```

Comment: Thanks Moody_Mudskipper! That is great.